# What is the difference in meanings caused by using different forms of of past tense here?

Tags: tense, past-perfect

> He **had been** there when the bell rang.

And

> He **was** there when the bell
> rang.

I think the latter is correct, but where I heard the sentence it was past perfect in which the sentence was said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't say which is correct without knowing the context.

*He was there when the bell rang* is a simple statement in the past tense.

The past perfect takes the incident one stage further back in the past.

*He told me that he had been there when the bell rang, but had not dared to open the door.* The subject spoke in the past about something that had happened earlier.

Answer (score 1):

First sentence is past perfect construction, while the second one is simple past construct.

First one implies, he had been there (for a while/for a few hours), when the bell rang.

Second one implies, when the bell rang, he happened to be there.